# In databinding, how to find which control invoked the "getter" of a property data-bound to it, when the PropertyChanged event is raised?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

I am developing a Silverlight 3 application, in which I have a boolean property in my Model class (using MVVM approach) that's bound to "IsEnabled" target property of two buttons. I need to find out which button invoked this boolean property when I raise the PropertyChanged event (i.e. during databinding).

Is there something in the callstack that I can look for to figure this out? Or is there some other way by which I can do this?

TIA...
Sudeep

Comment: Your question might indicate an architectural problem.  Why do you need to know which control?

Comment: Hi Michael, I would like to know this information while I am debugging my application (just so as to verify the veracity of my application logic).

Answer (score 0):

You could check the call stack e.g.

```
var st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
var callingtypeOfAMethod = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
```

i hope this gets you the idea. you can get the calling control type using this.

Comment: Hi Joachim, I tried checking this approach. What exactly should I be looking for in the callstack? Presently in my callstack I can see "[Native to Managed Transition]" as the previous stack member.